# Main app contains child apps but token not passed

Tags: c#, reactjs, identityserver4

I have 2 child apps that when I run each app individually, they are configured to use identity server v4 and the authentication flow (implicit) works as expected. Each app is redirected to the identity server login page.

Now I have a container app that has links to the other apps as shown here:

```
        <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <a href="#/app1">
                <li>
                    App 1
                </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#/app2">
                <li>
                    App 2
                </li>
            </a>
</div>
```

Now this container app is also configured with identity server using the grant type implicit.

When I log in with identity server and then click to load one of the child apps I get the error in identity server as :

> User is not authenticated.

The redirect URL from the child app looks correct.

In chrome the following URL failed:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:59418/connect/authorize?client_id=alchemylab_singleSpaAccess_implicit&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636867377068725779.MmY2MGU3ZjctOGY5Zi00OWQ3LWFlNmUtMTE2ZmMzY2JlNTNmM2U2ZTc3YTMtOGYxZi00YzQ4LWE0NjYtNzAwMzJlNDhiNDg0&state=CfDJ8Dif9mrvVj9At2AoKjgixXpfcTPQK9drG8hUZ4TTiBoT_XDOsPUg_fO63TfcTlbsknU1q6hYG1acfRToNRdjn8lX56it0XNQ0Y90itWy295U3V5T7w6b-uLvd3RPoOaexJpkQ36wbFWTF93i0Hz5fW0pzlmTv3BccslcoTR__QOu6X9SmPN95INQ1auYVtqTZcEkxrtBYeBSKrSvxVi-y778KcXgXDWmSAjxevSm6upVhzsNDtP4I3vLYjMMdMnoMZ-lDHZB0pEyfFL3JOgH9E8W_0SoWa7Tr8wTLWW47sZ3D75_ab1oZWTcM7vSZPO-WsbKb7ghmhQnpCWaiePidxY&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD1_4&x-client-ver=5.2.0.0' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5001/api/authDetails') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Although CORS errors are shown, CORS is set in the app.

If I try to run the above URL directly I see the follow error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   Exception: Correlation failed.
>   Unknown location
>
> Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()

I tried configuring all the apps to use grant type hybrid but I am seeing the same errors.

So do I need to do more than ensure each app works with identity server in order to get the container app working?

I was under the impression that the token id once the main container app is logged in, would be passed to the child app and a new access token would be sent back to the child app.

Comment: "I have 2 child apps that when I run each app individually, they are configured to use identity server v4 and the authentication flow (implicit) *works as expected*." How is the link above failing? Shouldn't it be the same as the request that worked from the client app?

Comment: The link is not the same (nonce is different). Could this be related to data protection? I do not have anything configured.

Comment: Can you post your configuration from Startup.cs? There might be something missing or incorrectly configured